# `:empty:hover` not being updated

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, vue.js

I developed a simple Tic-Tac-Toe game in [Vue.js](http://vuejs.org). I used a `table` to make the grid and use a `td:empty:hover { cursor: pointer }` to make the table cells appear as clickable elements for cursor-based input devices (i.e. a mouse, trackball).

This works initially, but upon starting a new game, any cells that were clicked in the previous game(s) do not appear to be "emptied" such that the `td:empty:hover` selector does not apply the `cursor: pointer`.

If I open Chrome's DevTools and apply the `:hover` pseudo-class manually via **Force element state**, the CSS pointer functionality is restored.

I feel like this might be a bug in Chrome, as the issue is not present in Safari or Firefox, but I wasn't sure if there was someone who might know something I don't know.

See below for instructions to replicate.

```js
var TicTacToe = new Vue({
  name: 'tictactoe',
  el: '#tictactoe',
  computed: {
    availableMoves () {
      var i = 0
      for (var r = 0; r < 3; r++) {
        for (var c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
          if (!this.grid[r][c]) {
            i++
          }
        }
      }
      return i
    },
    message () {
      if (this.winner) return (this.winner === -1) ? 'Tie game!' : this.winner + ' won!'
      if (this.currentPlayer) return this.currentPlayer + '\'s turn.'
      return 'X goes first.'
    }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      currentPlayer: null,
      winner: null,
      grid: [
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    checkForWinner () {
      // Check rows
      for (var r = 0; r < 3; r++) {
        if (!this.grid[r][0] || !this.grid[r][1] || !this.grid[r][1]) continue

        if (this.grid[r][0] === this.grid[r][1] && this.grid[r][1] === this.grid[r][2]) {
          this.winner = this.grid[r][0]
          return true
        }
      }

      // Check columns
      for (var c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
        if (!this.grid[0][c] || !this.grid[1][c] || !this.grid[1][c]) continue

        if (this.grid[0][c] === this.grid[1][c] && this.grid[1][c] === this.grid[2][c]) {
          this.winner = this.grid[0][c]
          return true
        }
      }

      // Check diagonals
      if (this.grid[0][0] && this.grid[1][1] && this.grid[2][2]) {
        if (this.grid[0][0] === this.grid[1][1] && this.grid[1][1] === this.grid[2][2]) {
          this.winner = this.grid[1][1]
          return true
        }
      } else if (this.grid[0][2] && this.grid[1][1] && this.grid[2][0]) {
        if (this.grid[0][2] === this.grid[1][1] && this.grid[1][1] === this.grid[2][0]) {
          this.winner = this.grid[1][1]
          return true
        }
      }

      // Tie Game
      if (this.availableMoves === 0) {
        this.winner = -1
        this.currentPlayer = null
        return true
      }

      return false
    },
    clickedCell (r, c) {
      if (this.winner || this.grid[r][c]) return

      this.grid[r][c] = this.currentPlayer || 'X'
      this.grid.splice(r, 1, this.grid[r])

      if (!this.checkForWinner()) {
        this.currentPlayer = (this.currentPlayer === 'O') ? 'X' : 'O'
      }
    },
    clickedNewGame () {
      this.currentPlayer = null
      this.winner = null
      this.grid = [
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]
      ]
      this.grid.splice(0, 1, this.grid[0])
    }
  }
});
```

```css
* { cursor: default }
body { font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale; padding-bottom: 100px; text-align: center }
h1 { font-weight: 400 }
h2 { font-weight: 300 }
button { background: none; border: none; display: inline-block; cursor: pointer; font-size: 22pt; padding: 0.25em }
button:hover { color: blue; }
#grid { border-collapse: collapse; font-size: 33pt; font-weight: 400; margin: 50pt auto }
#grid td { border: 3pt solid black; cursor: default; height: 50pt; padding: 0; width: 50pt }
#grid td:empty:hover { cursor: pointer }
#grid td:first-child { border-left: none }
#grid td:last-child { border-right: none }
#grid tr:first-child td { border-top: none }
#grid tr:last-child td { border-bottom: none }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.2/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="tictactoe">
    <h1>Tic-Tac-Toe</h1>
    <h2>{{ message }}</h2>
    <table id="grid">
      <tr v-for="r in [0, 1, 2]">
        <td v-for="c in [0, 1, 2]"
            @click="clickedCell(r, c)">{{ grid[r][c] || '' }}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    
    <button type="button"
            @click="clickedNewGame()">
      New Game
    </button>
  </div>
```

Instructions to replicate:

1. In Chrome, click a cell (for example, the bottom left cell) to start a game with an X in that position.
2. Click the new game button.
3. Use your cursor to hover over the previously chosen cell and notice that the cursor does not change to a `pointer` cursor (finger pointer icon, not the the arrow pointer icon).

**Note: I am running Google Chrome Version 62.0.3202.62 (Official Build) (64-bit) for macOS Sierra 10.12.6**

Comment: Seems to work in my version of Chrome (61.0.3163.100).

Comment: But not in an updated version (Version 62.0.3202.75 (Official Build) (64-bit)).

Comment: Thanks @Bert I added my version to the question. I guess this is might be an issue that was just introduced.

Comment: Might be a bug in `hover` moreso than `empty`. This pen seems to work. https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/MOYRwJ?editors=1100

Comment: Looks like if I just reorder the selectors (i.e. change `td:empty:hover` to `td:hover:empty` the problem is resolved. Thank you for helping me narrow down my problem.

Comment: Sure thing. That was a weird one.

Comment: You might at well make that `#grid td:empty { cursor: pointer }` - or how many other element states does cursor actually apply to :-)

Comment: Good idea @CBroe. Make that an answer and I will accept it. There is no need for the additional `:hover` part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't want to take away any due credit, @Bert - but since I was to lazy to update my Chromium to reproduce the issue, I was already about to ask you guys whether the problem persisted if you switched the pseudo class order.

But you might as well make that `#grid td:empty { cursor: pointer }` to begin with - or how many other element states does cursor actually apply to :-)

---

For me that is just a general, personal preference - I put as much into "normal" element state as possible, and `:hover` only adds what is essential for that state. Even for elements that I would only show *on* hover (such as a sub menu item), I tend to keep all that position:absolute, margin/padding etc. in the normal state (say, `ul > li > ul`), and only switch display to block in `ul > li:hover > ul`. But come to think of it, I suppose that stems in part from the old pre-"browser development tools" days, where you could not just "toggle" hover, but had to have the element visible to properly adjust styling in the first place, ha.